# Assigning entire column raising SetWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working through generating one large dataframe from multiple sources, and I'd like to set a column in each dataframe to designate the source before I concatenate all of them. However, this is raising a SetWithCopyWarning.

The warning suggests to use .loc to set values, but using this now raises two warnings instead of just one, now referencing self.obj[item] = s in the documentation.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df['Source'] = 'Source'
```

This second line is what is generating the warning.

Comment: so, dict is your dataframe?

Comment: temp is my dataframe in this case. Reading in multiple sheets from an Excel workbook saved them into a dict of dataframes, which I am iterating through in the for loop.

Comment: using dict as the name of a variable is not a great idea, because this can cause confusion with `dict()`. Also, if you do `pd.read_excel(...)` you get a `DataFrame`, not a dictionary. So, either your dict is not a dict, or your example is off. Could you check the type of dict?

Comment: You're right, that's a bad variable name. Went and changed it, and still had the same effect. I will edit the question with the new variable names. With regards to ```pd.read_excel(...)```, the documentation says that specifying ```sheet_name=None``` will return a dict of Dataframes.

Comment: You are right about the read_excel. Sorry about that. However, I cannot reproduce this warning, when looping through either a normal dict, or an ordered dict. I do get that exact warning if I loop through a dataframe, though.

Comment: I recreated it without doing any looping, just looking at a single DataFrame. I will edit the question above to remove the ambiguity of looping, as it seems like it isn't the looping/concatenating at the end.

Comment: What are the versions of `pandas`, `numpy` and `python` that you are using?

Comment: I am in ```pandas 0.23.0```, ```numpy 1.14.3```, and ```python 3.6.5```